# Database designing for a bug tracking system in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, asp.net-mvc-4, bug-tracking

I am an ASP.NET developer and I really dont do such of database stuff. But for my open source project on Codeplex I am required to setup a database schema for the project.

So reading from here and there I have managed to do the following.

[image]

As being new to database schema designing, I wanted some one else who has a better idea on this topic to help me identify any issues with this design.

Most of the relationships are self explanatory I think, but still I will jot each one down.

The two keys between *UserProfile* and *Issues* are for relationships between *UserId* and *IssueCreatedBy* and *IssueClosedBy*

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Good reading: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/issue_track_obj.htm#BJFBEAEI

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Not all inquiries need to be verbalized as questions: "I wanted some one else who has a better idea on this topic to help me identify any issues with this design."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks quite good, IMO your main issue is on naming consistency & simplicity.

- If each table identifier is `Id`, you should use it for all tables.
- Stay consistent with singular / plural in table names. I tend to prefer singular.

You can simplify a table name :

- `UserProfile` => `User`

As well as field names :

- `Issue_Title` => `Title`
- `Issue_Description` => `Description`
- `Issue_Priority_Type` => `Type` (or even less confusing: `Name`)

etc.

However I would use a more precise naming for foreign keys

- `CreatedBy` => `CreatedByUserId`
- `ClosedBy` => `ClosedByUserId`

HTH.

Comment: Anyone reading this, remember to stick to your particular SQL flavor coding/naming style. You can google online style guides for that.